# How do I use std::unique_ptr in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static-methods

What I'm trying to do is use `std::unique_ptr` to be able to open three different kinds of files (`.rdr`, `.rrd`, `.drr`), all of which have the base class `Reader`. The base class, as well as the three reader classes, are below:

```cpp
class Reader
{
protected:
  vector<Read> _reads;
}

class Reader1 : public Reader
{
private:
  int num;
};

class Reader2 : public Reader 
{
private:
  int num;
};

class Reader3 : public Reader
{
private:
  int num;
};
```

What I need help with is implementing the following function:

```cpp
static std::unique_ptr<Reader> create(const QString& file) {
// code here
}
```

This is my attempt so far:

```cpp
static std::unique_ptr<Reader> create(const QString& file)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Reader> (create(file)); // gives the error 'all paths through this function will call itself'
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function:

```cpp
if (tmp == "rdr") {
    file = createTempFile();

    auto readerfile = Reader::create(fileName);
```

I think I don't quite understand how `unique_ptr` works, which might be why I'm having trouble implementing this.

Comment: Where is the actual logic of creation of `Reader` from `file`? I suppose it should be in a constructor... but there isn't any.

Comment: Do you mean where is the implementation for the create function?

Comment: I mean, your create function calls... itself. Unconditionally. While it should do some logic to actually create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `create()` should be something like

```
static std::unique_ptr<Reader> create(const QString& file) {
    if (file == "<string for Reader1>")
       return std::make_unique<Reader1>(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What should go inside the parenethesis in (...)? I tried  putting std::make_unique<Reader1>(create(file)); but still get the same error 'all paths through this function will call itself.' Thanks!

Comment: @Kau `create(const QString& file)` calling `create(file)` is an endless recursive loop, that is what the compiler is warning you about. `std::make_unique<Reader1>(...);` calls the `Reader1` constructor passing `...` to it. So you need to pass to `make_unique<Reader1>()` whatever the `Reader1` constructor requires. Whether that be the filename to read, or the actual file data obtained from somewhere else. We can't answer that for you, because the class definitions you provided have no constructors defined!

Comment: That's the part I'm confused about is that I only have the default constructor ```Reader1() = default;``` so i'm not really sure what would go inside the (...). I tried passing in nothing but then get the error "unused function 'create'." I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor for `Reader`, and then you can create/make a `unique_ptr` and return from the function.

e.g.,

```
class Reader {
public:
Reader() = default;
Reader(std::string filename) {...}
...
};

std::unique_ptr<Reader> create(std::string filename) {
    return std::make_unique<Reader>(std::move(filename)); //requires C++17
}
```

Comment: Now it's giving me the warning "unused function 'create'." I think I do need to use the create function.

Comment: @Kau, You'd call `create` from somewhere else in your program to receive a `unique_ptr` to a `Reader`.

Comment: @chris I'm calling create from somewhere else in the program but still get the same error "unused function 'create'."

Comment: @Kau, Based on my experience, compilers are pretty good at not giving false positives with unused function warnings. Perhaps you're calling a different `create` function then. Really, anything I say is speculation because the question doesn't have a [mcve] that I can use to reproduce the warnings you get.